# MongoDB Filter documents and return only matched subdocument if exists, else null or empty array or empty object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to implement search/filter in my project. and i am new to mongodb.
I need all the documents matching the name and if there is an subdocument matching sID then only that subdocument should project in subdocument array.

But both documents matching name should display. Doesn't matter if there is any subdocument matching or not.

> My object is like:

```
[
        {
            "name" : "abcd",
            "education" : [
                {"sId" : 3233, "sName" : "XYZ"},
                {"sId" : 3244, "sName" : "SIO"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "abcd",
            "education" : [
                {"sId" : 3254, "sName" : "HDY"},
                {"sId" : 3245, "sName" : "UYT"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "qwerty",
            "education" : [
                {"sID" : 2212, "sName" : "SKJ"},
                {"sID" : 2133, "sName" : "SKJ"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "qwerty",
            "education" : [
                {"sID" : 2322, "sName" : "POS"},
                {"sID" : 1122, "sName" : "POS"}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

> And when i search {"name": "abcd", "sID": 3244}

Then output should be like:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "abcd",
        "education" : [
            {"sId" : 3244, "sName" : "SIO"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "abcd",
        "education" : []
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a match and project with filter on it with the query you want to match the element.

Example:

```
collection.aggregate([ 
{
    $match: {
    name : "abcd"
    }
},
{ 
    $project :  {
            name :1,
            education: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$education",
                as: "item",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.sId", 3244] }
              }
           }
   }
}
])
```